# How can I apply a style starting from the index of a NodeList?

Tags: javascript, css, arrays

I'm looking to "fade" elements progressively to the right of the *active* "step". I'm doing this by iterating through the NodeList and applying the opacity value incrementally. I'm having trouble resetting the loop to start with the *active* step. (It should have an opacity value of 1).

Pen: https://codepen.io/abenjamin/pen/JgyKGQ

HTML

```
<ul class="progress-stepper">
      <li class="step active">
        <p class="step--header">Overview</p>
        <p class="step--description">Iteratively touching base about game changers will make us leaders.</p>
      </li>
      <li class="step">
        <p class="step--header">Payments</p>
        <p class="step--description">Our business impacts markets to intelligently and grow our standard setter.</p>
      </li>
      <li class="step">
        <p class="step--header">Shipping</p>
        <p class="step--description">Globally synergising organic growths is crucial to our wholesale stand-up.</p>
      </li>
      <li class="step">
        <p class="step--header">Returns</p>
        <p class="step--description">Hello world! This is a test.</p>
      </li>
      <li class="step">
        <p class="step--header">Contacts</p>
        <p class="step--description">Hello world! This is a test.</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

JS

```
function fader(){
  for (i = 0; i < stepCount; i++) { 
    let fraction = 1/stepCount;
    let opacityValue = 1-(fraction*i);
    step[i].style.cssText = "opacity:"+opacityValue+";";
    console.log(opacityValue);
  };
};
```

Comment: More information is needed to answer your question. Specifically,  how did you create the `step` variable in your script?

Comment: step is a NodeList of the `li` under `.progress-stepper`.

Comment: **incrementally** would infer starting from zero - 0, 0.1, ..., 1. if the `li` with class `active` is first node and you want it to have an index of 1, then that would be **decremental** - 1, 0.9, ..., 0. which is your preferred option?

Comment: Also, it's important to see the code where you populate your `step` variable... please provide it, so that a good answer can be provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to pass the active step reference to the `fader()` function.
Consider the following `fader()` function

```
function fader(start){
  start = start||0;  
  let fraction = 1/(stepCount);  
  for (i = start; i < stepCount; i++) {    
    let opacityValue = 1-(fraction*(i - start));
    step[i].style.cssText = "opacity:"+opacityValue+";";
    console.log(opacityValue);
  };
}
```

1. Added a `start` parameter which will default to `0`.
2. The `fraction` value will be constant, removed it out of the loop.
3. Since the starting point of the loob will vary, updated the `opacityValue` to consider the starting point

Below is fork of the codepen with updated `fader()` function. Additionally updated the `moveStep()` to pass the `stepPlace` to `fader()` once it has been caluculated.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Eqvwyb

Comment: This is great. I appreciate the help! Initially, I was aiming to have the fraction adjust as the "count" of steps decrease, but I kinda like it the way it is. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're wanting the opacity to linearly "drop off" relative to the currently active step.

A simple solution for that would be to find the index of the active step by examining the `classList` of each node in your steps NodeList for the `active` class. Once found, you can then iterate the steps NodeList relative to this index, and calculate the step opacity accordingly.

For instance, you could update `fader()` as follows to achieve this:

```
function fader(){

  /* Calculate index of active step */
  let activeIndex = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < stepCount; i++) {
    if(step[i].classList.contains('active')) {
      activeIndex = i;
      break;
    }    
  }

  /* Iterate range of steps relative to activeIndex */
  for (i = activeIndex; i < stepCount; i++) { 

    /* Calculate linear opacity fall off for current step */
    let opacityAsc = (i - 1 - activeIndex) / (stepCount - activeIndex);
    let opacityDes = 1 - opacityAsc;

    step[i].style.opacity = opacityDes;
  };
};
```

Here's a modified fork of your codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mNMBba

hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would have to assume that the `li` nodes are in the order that they appear in the html file. If you want the index of the "active" node to be 1, then it is going to be a **decrement**  from 1 to 0.

What you have to ensure is proper distribution of opacity values from 1 to 0 depending on the size of the node list.

This is how you achieve that with minimal change to your existing code

```
function fader() { 

    const stepCount = step.length;

    const fraction = (stepCount>1) ? (1/(stepCount-1)) : 0; // if stepCount=3, opacity is 1, 0.5, 0, if stepCount=4, opacity is 1, 0.67, 0.33, 0 

    for (i = 0; i < stepCount; i++) { 

        let opacityValue = 1-(fraction*i); 

        step[i].style.cssText = "opacity:"+opacityValue+";"; 

        if (i === stepCount - 1) step[i].style.cssText = "opacity:0;"; // comment this line if you want to allow decimal values for last node

        console.log(opacityValue); 
     }; 
};
```

**Note**: you may get decimal values in your calculation but opacity will always start from one.